An error occurred: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple when using Spotipy functions
When I try to call .playlist_tracks() or .track(), and I send in string i get this error:
can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

            playlist_id = query.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
            print(playlist_id)
            try:
                playlist = spotify.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error while getting playlist data: {str(e)}')
                logging.error(f'Error while getting playlist data: {str(e)}')

Query is a URL returned from Discord. I've tried to force it to be str and everything.
Did they change how the want the input to those functions?
I've tried to use URL, URL or ID and all return the same error.

Could you please provide the query you have?

https://open.spotify.com/track/5iakizGd1KtTBXgx5SaTAO?si=2e5fbe57aa754ce2 i used this for .track()
and this for .playlist_tracks:
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3ntvwrQ3TSHo2k3wFjN62s?si=5d91acce14b24abc

It was a problem with my credential files, its contained extra "," after each credential. it fixed the problem.
